# Ruby Haml Variable Variables

Tags: ruby, variables, sinatra, haml

Iam working with Ruby and Iam trying to use a variable variable name :D

```
while count < iterationnumber.to_i
        @output = testtrim[count].tr(",", " ").delete('{').delete('}').delete('"').delete('[').delete(']')
        count +=1
end
```

I need to add "count" to @output to not just get one output for haml. Also if you know someting to strip away all these characters more eficiently I would be thankful.

Thanks in advance!

Benny

UPDATE

```
   get '/test' do
   keygen = "#{session["keygen"]}"
   puts keygen
    template = Addressable::Template.new("http://api.toodledo.com/2/tasks/get.php?key=#{keygen};modafter=1234567890;fields=folder,star,priority")
    uri = template7.expand({"keygen" => keygen})
    puts uri
    responseauth = RestClient.get(uri.to_s)
    testtrim = responseauth.split('}')
    iterationnumber = testtrim[0][22..-2]
    count = 0
    while count < iterationnumber.to_i
        @output = testtrim[count].tr(",", " ").delete('{}"[]')
        count +=1
    end
```

The problem now is, I don't know how to add the "count" number to @output, to output all of these splitet parts to haml. Maybe someone knows a better way to do that...

Thank you

Comment: You should include more information about what you’re trying to do. What’s `testtrim`? What does it contain? What do you want to produce from it? What are `count` and `iterationnumber`?

Answer (score 0):

Write as below

```
 @output = testtrim[count].tr(",", " ").delete('{}"')
```

No need to chain of calling `#delete` method as per the documentation :

[`delete([other_str]+) → new_str`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-delete)

> Returns a copy of str with *all characters in the intersection of its arguments* deleted.